# IOException getting thrown by ReaderWriteLockSlim?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a static class which is accessed by multiple threads and uses a ReaderWriterLockSlim in various methods to maintain thread safety. This works fine most of the time, however very intermittently I'm seeing an IOException handle is invalid error being thrown by one particular method as shown in the stack trace below. This has me greatly confused as I didn't even know that System.IO was involved in a ReaderWriterLock.

Any help at all in understanding where the error may be comming from would be greatly appreciated.

Stack Trace:

> System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.Reset()
>      at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.WaitOnEvent(EventWaitHandle waitEvent, UInt32& numWaiters, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
>      at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)

Code:

```
class Class1
{
    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim readwriteLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private const int readwriterlocktimeoutms = 5000;

    private static void myMethod(int ID)
    {
        bool IsTaken = false;
        bool isWriteLockTaken = false;

        if (!readwriteLock.TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock(readwriterlocktimeoutms))
        {
            throw new Exception("SafeGetSuItem: Error acquiring read lock");
        }
        else { IsTaken = true; }
        try
        {                
         // do some work which may require upgrading to a write lock depending on particular conditions
        }
        finally
        {
            if (IsTaken)
            {
                try
                {
                    readwriteLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
                    IsTaken = false;
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }                
        }
    }

}


enter code here

bool IsWriteTaken = false;
        try
        {
            if (!readerwriterlock.TryEnterWriteLock(readerwriterlocktimeout))
            {
                // log the error
            }
            else
            {
                IsWriteTaken = true;
            }

            if (IsWriteTaken)
            {
                // do some work
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (IsWriteTaken)
            {
                try
                {
                    readerwriterlock.ExitWriteLock();
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem logical, but is there any File I/O going on inside the try blocks?

Comment: And OT, there is no way to get in the finally block with IsTaken==false, and `catch {throw; }` can also be missed. Simplify your code and less can go wrong.

Comment: It looks to me like something else is disposing the reader/writer lock instance while your code is in the middle of trying to obtain the read lock. That destroys the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` instance's internal `EventWaitHandle`.

Comment: Are you using the 32 or 64-bit version of the framework? Also, how many CPU cores are on the machine? I'm not having any luck reproducing this exception, but it might be because I'm testing on a 32-bit single core Intel chip right now.

Comment: @Brian, 64bit, multi cores. The thing is that the methods will run sucessfully for hours or days on end with tens of thousands of calls before this occurs.

Comment: Could you post the code around upgrading upgrading the lock, and how that is exited?

Comment: @Johnv2020: Yeah, this almost *has* to be a subtle bug. Hours and days would be par for the course from an obscure low-level multithreaded bug.

Comment: @Henk, code added above. Its pretty simple just try to enter the write lock, do some work & finally if we got the write lock exit it

Comment: It looks OK, I hope you're not confusing `IsWriteTaken` and `isWriteLockTaken` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little weird. You *may* have stumbled upon a bug in the `WaitHandle` class. I picked this apart via Reflector and this is what I am seeing.

- Calling `Dispose` on the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` will call `Close` on the `EventWaitHandle` listed in the stack trace.
- Calling `Close` on a `EventWaitHandle` attempts to dispose the underlying `SafeHandle`.
- Calling `Reset` on a `EventWaitHandle` calls directly into the `ResetEvent` Win32 API from kernel32.dll and passes in the `SafeHandle`.
- I see no synchronization mechanisms in place that prevent a race between the disposing of a `SafeHandle` and having that instance consumed by the Win32 API.

Are you calling `Dispose` on the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` instance from another thread while `TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock` could be executing? This seems like the most likely scenario to me. Actually, this is the only scenario that I am seeing that would lead to an `IOException` being thrown.

It seems to me, based solely on my cursory analysis of the BCL code, that the `IOException` *could* be by-design, but it would make a whole lot more sense if Microsoft could somehow generate a `ObjectDisposedException` instead which happens on every single other attempt I have made to reproduce the problem. I would go ahead and report this to Microsoft.

Comment: But it can't throw `ObjectDisposedException` if thread B calls `Dispose` after the `Reset` called by thread A has done its check to see if the object has been disposed.

Comment: @Jim: The dispose check must be happening inside the `SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef` method which has a "hidden" implemenation. What if `SafeHandle.Close` and `SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef` are being called simultaneously? I am not seeing any synchronization in the BCL that prevents this.

Comment: @Brian, thanks for your analysis. The thing is I'm not disposing the readerwriterlockslim at any stage. The only calls ever made to it are one of the folloiwng, tryenterupgradeablereaderlock, exitupgradeablelock, tryenterwritelock & exitwritelock. The class itself is static and the readerwriterlockslim is private static so nothing should ever be able to dispose of it.

Comment: @Brian - sorry I don't have reflector (its no longer free), where are you seeing the SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef call ?

Comment: @Johnv2020: The P/Invoke interop automatically calls `DangerousAddRef` when passing a `SafeHandle` to a Win32 API function. I have attempted to reproduce the problem but only ever get an `ObjectDisposedException` from `DangerousAddRef`.

Comment: @Johnv2020: Well since you are not calling `Dispose` on the RWLS then that almost certainly falsifies my theory. I guess it *could* be possible that the application domain is being terminated which is causing the finalizer on `SafeHandle` to get called. That is more of a stretch than my original theory though. I am stumped.

Comment: There is some seriously convoluted code inside ReaderWriterLockSlim.cs. My brain hurts.